# prevent restarting fragment when switch tab

Tags: android, tabs, fragment

I created an android project that contains some tabs with fragmentActivity and each tab is a Fragment. when I am in a tab and select another tab and again back to previous tab, tab starts again. how can I keep state of tab and prevent recreation of fragment on tab switch?

Comment: Is it with every tab switch or does it only occur when you switch more tabs than 1. For instance swiping from tab 1 to tab 3?

Comment: No.It is for every tab switch.